# How to make a program skip the task bar (task list) in GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, x11, taskbar, gambas

I'm coding a demon like program from Gambas on Ubuntu 13.10.
This is a GUI application which becomes visible when the user hits specific key.
Therefore, I don't want this program to appear on the task bar.

[image]

Is there a way I can bypass it? (Maybe from a Bash trick or a Gambas code?)
Thanks! :)

Comment: http://gambasdoc.org/help/comp/gb.qt/window/skiptaskbar

Comment: Thanks NM! I found the update one here: http://gambasdoc.org/help/comp/gb.desktop/desktopwindow/skiptaskbar?v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR` atom to `_NET_WM_STATE` - see ['Application window properties'](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2731686) part of emwh spec.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know at all gambas, but what you want is the following for gtk (in python):

```
 window.set_property("skip-taskbar-hint", True)
```

or for QT:

```
setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen)
```

basically, you need to find a way to change the properties or flags for the windows you want to display. Look at the API of the windows in gambas

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP mentioned a "Bash trick"…

If you're OK installing a helper program from your distro's repositories, `wmctrl` can do this with a lot less fuss than any other solution I've found so far.

```bash
wmctrl -b add,skip_taskbar -r 'The Window Name'
```